# Where is dash being used as default shell?

Tags: bash, scripts, dash-shell

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh:

> The default login shell remains bash. Opening a terminal from the menu
>   or shortcut [crtl-alt-t] provides interactive bash. A script run from
>   the desktop or file manager, through the dialogue 'run in terminal'
>   will execute as POSIX dash.

```
livy@disco-dingo:~$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug 22 10:53 /bin/sh -> dash
livy@disco-dingo:~$ cat Desktop/test.sh
echo $SHELL > ~/Desktop/test-result.txt;
```

I added the execute permission, then double clicked the `test.sh` file and here was the result:

```
livy@disco-dingo:~$ cat Desktop/test-result.txt 
/bin/bash
```

Is the Ubuntu wiki out of date or something?

Comment: @steeldriver I tried it. `echo $0` output the current running script, which is `/home/livy/Desktop/test.sh`.

Comment: Apologies - it's actually trickier than I remembered. You may need to resort to `readlink "/proc/$$/exe"`: see for example [Why is echo $SHELL always showing /bin/bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330242/65304)

Answer (score 2):

According to nixCraft: [How do I find out what shell I am using on Linux/Unix?](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-what-shell-im-using.html)

> ... `$SHELL` is the shell for the current user but not necessarily shell that is running at the movement. *[sic]*

I have no idea how to get the currently running shell. The following just gives the name of the script:

```
ps -p $$ > ~/Desktop/test-result.txt
```

While the following:

```
pstree -s $$ > ~/Desktop/test-result.txt
```

has the following output on my computer:

```
systemd---test.sh---pstree
```

To see if `dash` is running at all, you can try:

```
pgrep dash > ~/Desktop/test-result.txt
```

Check first in an interactive shell that it isn't already running to avoid false positives. On my computer, even when I have `#!/bin/dash`, `dash` does not appear to be used. So it seems `systemd` may be running the script directly.

Comment: I am now at home and using Lubuntu. That thing does not allow me to double click to run a script -- it always opens the script in Visual Studio Code. I will try that `ps` command again at my workplace tomorrow.

Comment: `ps -p $$` outputs `PID=7971 TTY=tty2 TIME=00:00:00 CMD=sh`, while `pgrep dash` outputs nothing.

Comment: Seems like your computer is using `sh` to run the script?

Comment: Yeah, kinda. I'll try to do some more experiment and see how it works. It shall take some time, but then I will come back and share the result. It is quite of a mess with several shells installed by default though.

Comment: Just a quick update, the `ps` command is not very reliable. When being used inside `~/.profile`, it just prints out `CMD=/etc/gdm3/Xsession` which is the parent script. The `$SHELL` is indeed useless -- it is the top level shell (login shell) for current user. From PowerShell: `PS /home/livy> $env:SHELL` and the result is `/bin/bash` lol.